# GRUB error 13: invalid or unsupported executable format on custom kernel

Tags: operating-system, nasm, osdev, grub, bochs

I am trying to learn OS Dev and I started building my own kernel based on [The Little book about OS Development](https://littleosbook.github.io/).

When I loaded the kernel using bochs GRUB complains with:

```
error 13: invalid or unsupported executable format
```

The files I'm using:

#### loader.s

```
global loader

MAGIC_NUMBER equ 0xBADB002
FLAGS equ 0x0
CHECKSUM equ -MAGIC_NUMBER

section .text
align 4
    dd MAGIC_NUMBER
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM

loader:
    mov eax, 0xCAFEBABE
.loop:
    jmp .loop
```

#### link.ld

```
ENTRY(loader)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x00100000;

    .text ALIGN (0x1000) :
    {
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata ALIGN (0x1000) :
    {
        *(.rodata*)
    }

    .data ALIGN (0x1000) :
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss ALIGN (0x1000) :
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

#### bochsrc.txt

```
megs:              32
display_library:    sdl
romimage:           file=/usr/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-latest
vgaromimage:        file=/usr/share/bochs/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest
ata0-master:        type=cdrom, path=os.iso, status=inserted
boot:               cdrom
log:                bochslog.txt
clock:              sync=realtime, time0=local
cpu:                count=1, ips=1000000
```

#### menu.lst

```
default=0
timeout=0

title First OS
kernel /boot/kernel.elf
```

commands to execute:

```
nasm -f elf32 loader.s
ld -T link.ld -melf_i386 loader.o -o kernel.elf
genisoimage -R -b boot/grub/stage2_eltorito -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -A os -input-charset utf8 -quiet -boot-info-table -o os.iso iso
bochs -f bochsrc.txt
```

My files structure is like this:

```
os_dev
  |--(rest of the files)
  |--iso
    |-- boot
      |-- kernel.elf
      |-- grub
        |-- menu.lst
        |-- stage2_eltorito
```

The file stage2_eltorito was downloaded from https://github.com/littleosbook/littleosbook/blob/master/files/stage2_eltorito

Comment: I just realized. If you are using mulitboot shouldn't the line in menu.lst be `multiboot /boot/kernel.elf`

Comment: Just tried your recommendation. It seems like it makes things worse as grub now does not undrstand the menu.lst file and throws me a grub terminal to figure it out manually.

Comment: Tried this: `menuentry "First OS"\n
{\n
    multiboot /boot/kernel.elf\n
    boot\n
}`
Still the same happens...

Comment: I did that as you said I just dont know how to do the newline thing in the comments code style

Comment: I still get the grub terminal... I don't think my problem was in menu.lst file since its exactly as the tutorial indicates it should be

Comment: menu.lst is old style, grub moved to grub.cfg long ago

Comment: Yes but remember im not using the latest grub. Instead im using the stage2_eltorito file provided by the book. I think its grub version 0.97

Comment: Okay you didn't mention you were using grub legacy

Comment: Well that's because I'm not 100% aware of what is happening. This is meant to be a tutorial :)

Comment: Okay go back to what you had originally. One issue I just noticed is a typo. Shouldn't `MAGIC_NUMBER equ 0xBADB002` be `MAGIC_NUMBER equ 0x1BADB002` ?

Comment: Okay now I feel stupid... Thanks man I can't believe i missed this... I was stuck for 2 hours....

Answer (score 1):

Michael Petch noticed that B. Kostas was using an incorrect Magic Number for Grub Legacy.

Changing `MAGIC_NUMBER equ 0xBADB002` in `loader.s` to `MAGIC_NUMBER equ 0x1BADB002` solved the issue.